# ubuntu set up virtual host when I have zf2

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, ubuntu-14.04

I have set up the zf2 on my ubuntu 14.04 system using following link 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/overview.html
This is working find for me and this has been set up in my /var/www/html/zf2
I have followed all the instruction given in the tutorial for virtual host as well, but now when I place any other php file in my /var/www/html/test.php this does not get execute.

Am really not sure what mistake am doing.

For more details
My hosts file contains

```
127.0.0.1       zf2.local localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/zf2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName zf2.local
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zf2/public
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory /var/www/html/zf2/public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

It would be really helpful if anyone can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to view standalone PHP files you should be putting them in `/var/www/html/zf2/public`, not `/var/www/html`. There's no way for the browser to access files outside of the document root.

Comment: Thanks @tim-fountain, Is there any way I can make this normal, So as my php file start executing in my www directory and existing zf2 will also keep as it is.

Comment: I want it to work as localhost/test.php. I have already tried to place the file in zf2 public directory and it works for me. but I really don't want to place all my test code inside zf2. I need it to be a separate directory like www/zf2, www/test.php, www/project1 etc

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood. In that case you definitely shouldn't put your ZF2 app in `/var/www/html/` (this is a security risk). Put it at something like `/var/www/zf2`. Then you can keep your localhost files in `/var/www/html/`, and everything will work as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another virtual host like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```